# View is not gone, sometimes

Tags: iphone

There is a very hard issue I'm trying to pursue. In the `viewDidAppear:` I have the following code:

```
if(dataSourceCount > 0)
{
    [scrollView setHidden:NO];
    UIView *ndView = [self.view viewWithTag:204];
    [ndView removeFromSuperview];
    self.noDataView = nil;
    infoBtn.hidden = NO;
}
else
{
    [scrollView setHidden:YES];
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NoDataView" owner:self options:nil];
    self.noDataView.tag = 204;
    [self.view addSubview:self.noDataView];
    infoBtn.hidden = YES;
}
[super viewDidAppear:animated];
```

The problem occurs on `if true` case, very rarely and as a result on the device I can see the view that has been removed from superview - `ndView`.

I was thinking that viewWithTag may return nil sometimes, but this is not the case as I found out from debug. Also tried to move `self.noDataView = nil` to `else` and found the issue again.

Is there any obvious or non-obvious mistake that I'm doing here, which I'm not supposed? The idea of this code snippet is to temporarily show some other view, while data is not available.

Comment: What happens if the false case happens twice?, when you leave the view, does it remove the view from its superview?, if your navigation controller doesnt deallocate your viewController, i think it may preserve subviews that were added? First thought thats popped into my head

Comment: I don't have any navigation associated with this controller. It is wrapped into tab view controller, so I'm just changing data and switching tab. I'll put some logs to see if else may be called twice.

Comment: You are right, sometimes `else` is called twice. You may submit it as an answer to accept. Thanks.

Comment: follow-up to your previous question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395935/how-to-make-uiviewcontroller-re-load-the-view

Comment: @falconcreek, doesn't have anything to do with previous question.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if that solves your problem but:

1. `[super viewDidApper:animated]` should be on the firstline within your viewDidAppear Method
2. I'd move your code to `viewWillAppear`

Maybe this helps a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Submitting this as an answer rather than a comment

'What happens if the false case happens twice?, when you leave the view, does it remove the view from its superview?, if your navigation controller doesnt deallocate your viewController, i think it may preserve subviews that were added? First thought thats popped into my head'

The problem is that your subview was being added multiple times, and removed once. Thus when you expected it to be removed, it was only removing the top one.

I'd recommend having the view as an instance variable, so that every time you add and remove the subview, it is pointing to the same one.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!self.noDataView)
{
  [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NoDataView" owner:self options:nil];
}
```